# how to find the index of records with different types in series of pandas in python?

Tags: python, pandas

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
   ...: df=pd.Series([True,"a",1])
   ...: df
Out[1]: 
0    True
1    a
2    1
dtype: object
```

How can I get the record of `int` type supposing there are thousands of data of different dtypes("int","str","boolean") in a series?
  And how can I get the records of other types like "str", "boolean"?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  The type here is 'object' because True, 'a' and 1 are all different types.  If you want a series of type int then you have to have all ints (maybe with some NaNs).  What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I got a raw series with different dtypes,I want to preserve the records of "int" type and delete others.Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you want to keep the columns with only ints, or the rows with int column values?

Comment: Yes and I want to find a common way to clean the series of different dtypes.Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use boolean indexing  `type` and ``.apply here:

```
int_records = df[df.apply(type) == int]
bool_records = df[df.apply(type) == bool]
str_records = df[df.apply(type) == str]
```

if there are a lot of type to compare you can do it easier by

```
type_series = df.apply(type)

# or type_series = [type(x) for x in df]


int_records = df[type_series == int]
bool_records = df[type_series == bool]
str_records = df[type_series == str]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that understand your task exactly but maybe it could help you. I'm working with python 2.7, but suppose that it works in Python 3+

I know three ways to define type of variable:
1) using **class**

```
for value in df:
    if value.__class__ == int:
        value
```

or

```
int_list = [value for value in df if value.__class__ == int]
```

2) using isinstance ([check docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance))

```
for value in df:
    if isinstance(value,bool) is True:
        value
```

3) as remind Maarten Fabré, it could be type(obj)

```
int_list = [value for value in df if type(value) == int]
```

Additionally if you need, you can enumerate it and get indices of this values. Or append these values to some list.

Comment: I think `type(obj)` is cleaner than `obj.__class__`, and the `isinstance is problematic for because `isinstance(False, int) == True`

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed some problem with isinstance too — it may determine boolean as int.

And type(obj) is really cleaner. I'll add it. Thank you